# Defining a custom Error measure (sMAPE) function

Tags: r

I am defining a custom sMAPE (Symmetric Mean Absolute Percent Error)  function in R. I want to add an exception in the code where both actual and predicted are zero.

Here is the sample data:

Actual        Predicted
0                    0
2                    1
1                    0
2                    4
2                    1
1                    3

The code is shown below:

```
sMAAPE <- function(actual, predicted){
if (actual == 0 & predicted == 0){
    return(0)
       }
else {
  output<- mean(abs(actual-predicted)/(abs(actual)+abs(predicted)))
  return(output)
    }
  }
```

As I mentioned, i want to add an exception, that is wherever both actual and predicted are 0, my error would be zero. The problem with my code is that, when it is encountering both actual and predicted to be 0 in first observation, it is giving the mean error to be zero, but in reality I want mean of all errors.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Instead of `if/else` use `ifelse` with index created using `rowSums` ie. `i1 <- !rowSums(df1 != 0); ifelse(i1, 0, othervalue)`  Wrap it in a function `sMAAPE <- function(dat) { i1 <- !rowSums(dat !=0); val <- with(dat, mean(abs(actual-predicted)/(abs(actual)+abs(predicted)))); val[i1] <- 0; val}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying @akrun's suggestion in the comments to your problem. I think this is what you need.

```
# Create a dataset    
Actual <- c(0,2,1,2,2,1)
Predicted <- c(0,1,0,4,1,3)
df <- data.frame(cbind(Actual, Predicted))
df


sMAAPE <- function(actual, predicted){
     output<- ifelse(actual == 0 & predicted == 0,0, # If actual and predicted are 0, error is 0 
     abs(actual- predicted)/(abs(actual)+abs(predicted))) # otherwise your function
     return(mean(output)) # Return mean of all errors
}
```

The output:

```
> sMAAPE(df$Actual, df$Predicted)
[1] 0.4166667
```

Which is the mean of the following vector `[1]       0 0.3333333 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.5000000`

You could add `na.rm = T` to the mean function so it handles NA's as well.

Comment: This is also working. 

Also, if we add na.rm = T in mean function, this will not consider those NA's at all, therefore the mean would be wrong as the length of df will change after excluding NA's. To deal with this, I used na.rm = T is sum function and then diving this sum with length of dataframe.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, Here is the code:

 
output_sum<- sum(abs(actual-predicted)/(abs(actual)+abs(predicted)), na.rm = T)
output <- output_sum/NROW(actual)
return(output)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `actual == 0 & predicted == 0` is a logical vector, while if you put a logical vector as the condition of if sentence, only the first element will be judged.

Use `sum(abs(actual))+sum(abs(predicted)) == 0` instead in the condition.

Comment: This worked. Using sum function allows R to go the else condition. Thanks